# Meaning of "a couple of bucketfuls that had been discoloured in the accident taken away"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> When daylight came on the morning after the shooting, blood could beseen on the sea pebbles of the turn-around in front of the house. Two petroltins were found behind a tree. The pebbles were raked, **a couple of bucketfuls that had been discoloured in the accident taken away.**

Dose "a couple of bucketfuls" refer to pebbels and mean a lot of, so  the whole sentence mean: a lot of pebbles were discolored in the accident that had happened?
can bucketful means as a bucket? I searched but I did not find it means as a bucket.

Source: A Story Of Lucy Gault by William Trever.

Comment: "a couple of bucketfuls": about two buckets of pebbles, but [**bucketful**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bucketful) can be used quite differently (see linked example).

Answer (score 1):

A "bucketful" is the quantity that would fill a bucket. This is rather vague, but probably in the range of  2-5 gallons.

The boldface text means that roughly two bucketfuls (say at least 3-4 gallons or 12-16 liters) of pebbles had been discolored in the accident and were subsequently taken away. The given text does not say how the pebbles were discolored, I am guessing by bloodstains.

Comment: Lots of thanks, So Dose "discolored pebbles" in this context mean: bloody pebbles and the whole sentence mean: about two bucketfuls of bloody pebbles were taken away by someone who had seen discolored pebbles?

Comment: @Viser I am guessing about blood. I haven't read the story, and don't know what "the shooting" was. Maybe they were discolored by motor oil or something else, but blood is mentioned. Maybe the story tells who took the pebbles away, but the text quoted doesn't.say. . Perhaps there was a landscaping service, i have no context here.

Comment: Presumably detectives investigating the shooting would take away bloodstained pebbles as evidence.